# Find classes with single property

Tags: c#, regex

**Tl;DR;**
What is the regex to find c# classes that posses only a single string property? (no methods or other properties)

**Long Story:**
I'm now leading tech leading a team that maintain several solutions. Looking around I found out a lot of cases of `Dictionary<string, SpecialValue>` where `SpecialValue` is a class that contain a single public string property named "value".
The ideia here is that, the resulting Json be like `{"dictionaryKey":{value:"myValue"}}`.
I want to find out how many cases we have like this.
Visual Studio can use regex search, so... what is the regex for finding a class that has a single string property?

Comment: Runtime? I think what you need is Reflection and Not Regex

Comment: no, it's not on runtime... it's on compile time

Comment: Get the type with `instance.GetType()` or `typeof(type)` and then check for zero methods with `type.GetMethods().Length == 0` and only one string property with `type.GetProperties().Length == 1 && type.GetProperties()[0].PropertyType == typeof(string)`. You can make a unit test project to run against your proyect for the compile-time scenario.

Comment: @mishamosher Why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @nhouser9 The question is kind of unclear, I'm waiting to see if that particular comment resolves _Leonardo_ issue to rephrase it correctly and post as answer

Comment: You can't parse C# code with a regex.  You'll want to use a proper code analysis tool that can actually successfully parse and semantically analyze C# code.

Comment: @Leonardo The string property named "value", its always auto-implemented? Also, this string, can it be a field, or it is always a property?

Comment: You want to use the .NET Compiler Platform, called "Roslyn," to analyze the source code. It'll take a little bit of work, but well worthwhile. Get Roslyn from https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn. Search the 'net for tutorials. Lots of Roslyn questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: @Leonardo In the supposition that the class always has only one public string auto-property, no methods, inheritance, generics or whatsoever, as an example `class Test{public String Value{get;set;}}` is a valid case, a possible Visual Studio regex would be `class[\r\n\t\f ]+[^\d]\w*[\r\n\t\f ]*{[\r\n\t\f ]*public[\r\n\t\f ]+(string|String)[\r\n\t\f ]+[^\d]\w*[\r\n\t\f ]*{[\r\n\t\f ]*get[\r\n\t\f ]*;[\r\n\t\f ]*set[\r\n\t\f ]*;[\r\n\t\f ]*}[\r\n\t\f ]*}`. This regex will not identify if the class is commented, so it will catch cases like `//class Test{public String Value{get;set;}}`.

Comment: @mishamosher pls have this as an answer! this captured a bunch of cases (not sure if all)

Comment: @Leonardo Wanted to post it as answer originally but your question was put _on hold_. Now that it is not _on old_, I have posted it as an answer (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Visual Studio support for regex search is kind of short. It doesn't support `\s`, `\W`, `\B`, and a bunch more of patterns.

In the supposition that all the classes have always only one public string auto-property, with no methods, inheritance, generics, or whatsoever, as an example the class:

```
class Test
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

the regex given by:

```
class[\r\n\t\f ]+[^\d]\w*[\r\n\t\f ]*{[\r\n\t\f ]*public[\r\n\t\f ]+(string|String)[\r\n\t\f ]+[^\d]\w*[\r\n\t\f ]*{[\r\n\t\f ]*get[\r\n\t\f ]*;[\r\n\t\f ]*set[\r\n\t\f ]*;[\r\n\t\f ]*}[\r\n\t\f ]*}
```

should cover the majority of the cases. Please note that the previous regex will also catch classes that are into comments or in a illegal place. For example, classes commented out or declared inside methods will be catched by this regex, as it only searches for string literals and does not check all the syntax that C♯ requires (it is an impossible job for regexes anyway).